# How to always add all imports to new Python files?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I am working on a Python project in PyCharm.

Every time I create a new file, I have to import all of the basic libraries again. I keep getting kicked out of my workflow for a few seconds every time I notice that I forgot to import a library.

As far as I can tell, there is no reason not to just import every library I use anywhere in every single file, or is there? I would much rather import a library I don't need than risk losing my concentration because I forgot to import something and have to waste a few seconds on it. Since the auto-sorting of libraries doesn't seem to work properly, I even have to add the import statement manually.

Is there a way to give PyCharm a large list of libraries and just import those in absolutely every file by default?

For comparison, this is possible to do in Jupyter Lab: You can have one notebook that contains all import statements, and just call "%run import_everything.ipynb" in all the other notebooks. This has saved me a lot of time, and is also much more readable than having different imports in every notebook.

(I care specifically about how to do this in PyCharm, but if there is a more generic way to do it, that information would also be appreciated)

Comment: Just don't create new files but create a skeleton-script with imports of all your basic packages and has a main()-function and its call and open this script when starting something new. Just open it, store it under a new name and you can do that as many times as you want.

Comment: This only works for creating new files. Is there a way to also adjust all existing files? When I realize I want to use a new library, I would like to add it to all my existing files as well, in case I need it elsewhere as well, later.

Comment: If you're looking for a less complicated solution to this, you might want to look at code snippets, this way you can just write an abbreviation and it'd write all the import statements, it's not exactly what you're looking for but it would probably still save a lot of time. Look for an example tutorial from jetbrains [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-creating-and-applying-live-templates-code-snippets.html#template-abbreviation)

Comment: How many files are we talking? It should not be too much of a struggle to import a library to an existing file once you try to use a function from it. The moment you write some code with a function from a library you did not import, you'll notice because auto complete and tool tips don't work. Then you can just import it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short script to go over all my files and combine all basic import statements. It also wraps it in comments that say "BASIC IMPORTS", so in the future I can just use PyCharms "replace string in whole project" feature to mass-replace all imports by looking for these comments with a regex.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

p = Path(__file__).absolute().parent.parent
excluded_files = ['__init__.py', 'setup.py']
affected_files = [a for a in p.glob('**/*.py') if a.name not in excluded_files]
acc = {}
for a in affected_files:
    b = a.read_text()
    b = b[:b.index("\n\n")]
    finds = re.findall("(import |from )(.*)", b)
    for c in finds:
        acc[c] = True
        assert "intnet" not in c[1], a

lst = list(acc.keys())
lst.sort(key=lambda a: a[1])

res = '\n'.join(f"{a[0]}{a[1]}" for a in lst)
res = "# BASIC IMPORTS\n" + res + "\n# / BASIC IMPORTS"

for a in affected_files:
    b = a.read_text()
    b = res + b[b.index("\n\n"):]
    a.write_text(b)
```